# Skip creating some DB tables from third-party packages

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using `django-celery` package. And I need just functionality for PeriodicTasks and I do not need some of the tables, such as:
`djcelery_workerstate, djcelery_taskstate, etc.`

Is there is a way to skip creating some of the tables?

Something like `admin.site.unregister(ModelName)` in admin.

Comment: Why do you care?  Just let Django create the tables, it doesn't hurt.  (Moreover, it doesn't sound like the tables you mentioned are not needed for periodici tasks.)

Answer (score 0):

Some times you can use the [`fake` migration flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate--fake) to mark them as run but not actually executing them.
In this case though, all those tables are created in the [initial  migration](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/migrations/0001_initial.py), so you cannot 'fake' them.

One way to answer what you're asking for would be to edit this file before running the migration, though, some tables might be needed for Celery to work properly, or might be needed in a future release. So maybe not a wise thing to do :)